# How can i import simple_links and downloadable_links of downloadable products?

Tags: magento2, product, downloadable, download-link

i want to import downloadable products, which have multiple sample_links and downloadable_links, My Magento app is multi store site.
like i have 7 multistore/multilingual, each product belongs to different or same stores the title and description of each product is different with each store.
so once import a single product i am doing like this:
[sample code](https://gist.github.com/ahmadwaliesipick/36e11b2e2c28ab09ea9ef3b33c11c2e7)

So how can i add the sample_links and downloadable_links for downloadable products?

Answer (score 0):

you can add downloadableinfo array in your importdata like below:

```
                $downloadableInfo=['price'=>'10',
                'url'=>'https://firebearstudio.com/media/logos/default/logo.png'
                ,'downloads'=>'10',
                'group_title'=>'Downloadable links title',
                'title'=>'Link title 1'];

                foreach ($currentStores as $currentStore){

                    $importData[] = [
                        'sku'  => $sku,
                        'name'  => $name,
                        'price'  => $price,
                        'description'  => $description,
                        'product_type' => $product_type,
                        'store_view_code' => $currentStore['code'],
                        'downloadable_links'=>$downloadableInfo,
                    ];
                }
```

Comment: this doesnot works, how should we add if there are more than 1 downloadable links and what about the sample links?